# Reading a Binary file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, binaryfiles

I have a binary file that I want to read. I don't really know what the file looks like. However, I do know each message contains a header, some message specific fields, and a termination string which is "DBDBDBDB"

This is what the file contains:

- Header

  - marker(uint16_t) this will equal "ST" in the message
  - msg_type(uint8_t)
  - sequence_id(uint64_t)
- Order Entry Message

  - Header
  - price(uint64)
  - qty(uint32)

(And some other data, but this is the gist of it.)

This file is a data stream from an exchange which contains interaction between different traders, and my job is to decode the stream.

My problem is, I don't know how to display the contents of this binary file so I can't appropriately store the data into a structure.

i've tried the following, and it crashes my cmd window while printing out gibberish.

```
struct Header
{
        uint16_t marker;
        uint8_t msg_type;
        uint64_t sequence_id;
        uint64_t timestamp;
        uint8_t msg_direction;
        uint16_t msg_len;
 };
 void parseFile(string filename)
 {
   streampos size;
    Header h;

    ifstream file (filename, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
      file.read ((char*)&h.marker, sizeof(h.marker));
      file.read ((char*)&h.msg_type, sizeof(h.msg_type));
      file.read ((char*)&h.sequence_id, sizeof(h.sequence_id));
      file.read ((char*)&h.timestamp, sizeof(h.timestamp));
      file.read ((char*)&h.msg_direction, sizeof(h.msg_direction));
      file.read ((char*)&h.msg_len, sizeof(h.msg_len));
      file.close();
    }
  cout<<h.marker<<endl;
  cout<<h.msg_type<<endl;
  cout<<h.sequence_id<<endl;
  cout<<h.timestamp<<endl;
  cout<<h.msg_direction<<endl;
  cout<<h.msg_len<<endl;

}
```

However, the result I am getting is not the ones I am expecting; I am getting

```
50

16654955463245608
9850698347210351
8
34
```

I am expecting the first line to be 'ST', and the second line to be either 1,2,3

Also, the protocol of the message is Little Endian, and I am using windows7, which is also little endian.

If anyone can give me pointers or point me to the right direction i would greatly appreciate it.

This is a different question from previously posted question because the previous solution does not work for me, and I am dealing with extra data types.

Much thanks.

Comment: You want to read a binary file but you *don't* have the format?

Comment: I must be missing something here. Do i NEED to know the format beforehand? Can't I just print out the file and see what it looks it?

Comment: Use `myfile.read()` to read binary data.

Comment: @weizeng *Can't I just print out the file and see what it looks it?* Open it in notepad and tell me if what you see makes any sense.

Comment: Of course not. But shouldn't the binary reader option in fstream convert the binary code into something readable?

Comment: @weizeng Binary reader? theres no such thing, if youre talking about the binary flag thats related to \r\n conversion. It doesnt interpret the data any more than that.

Comment: @weizeng Binary mode only inhibits conversion of newline characters on platforms where that is necessary. (A slight exaggeration; there are platforms where the difference is significant, but the probability of you using such a machine is zero.)

Comment: Ok so what do i do here guys, im at a loss....
I've also added extra info in the question

Comment: What's wrong with [`fstream::read`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) ?

Comment: I recommend moving the reading functionality into the class, something like `binary_read(std::istream& input);`.  This allows you to declare the variables as private and employ the concepts of *data hiding* and *encapsulation*.

Comment: @Thomas, but first I need to figure out how this binary file works and how to store it into a structure

Comment: Hey guys I still haven't found my solution yet. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're seeing right now is that `istream::read` wants a pointer to char, and you're passing some other type. You can get this much of the code working by taking an address and casting it:

```
file.read ((char *)&h.marker, sizeof(h.marker));
```

Then you need to add similar `read` calls for the other fields, of course (but it is good that you're adding *one* thing, getting it to work, *then* moving on to more).

Comment: Ok, Im getting closer, it populates the struct, but not with what I was expecting. I'm going to update my post with my results.

Comment: I did file.read ((char *)&h.marker, sizeof(h.marker));

The output shows that its a smiley face or other random integers...